# Странности canvas в Firefox

Tags: javascript, canvas, firefox

есть код

```
        .....
        canvas.height = sq;
        canvas.width = sq;

        context.translate(sq / 2, sq / 2);
        context.rotate((img.rotate * Math.PI) / 180);
        var z1=-sq / 2;
        context.drawImage(pic, z1, z1);
        pic.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        canvas.height = crop.height;
        canvas.width = crop.width;
        x = (sq - crop.width) / 2;
        y = (sq - crop.height) / 2;

        context.drawImage(pic, x, y, crop.width, crop.height, 0, 0, crop.width, crop.height);
        ....
```

который обрезает, масштабирует, поворачивает. В хроме всё работает отлично, но в Firefox глючит странно - по шагам, в отладчике, всё отрабатывает правильно, а в реалтайме не хочет выполнять, похоже, эту команду context.drawImage. Есть подозрение, что переход к следующей строке кода переходит быстрее, чем текущая строка выполнит все необходимые действия.  Полный код примера можно скачать https://github.com/JonHappy/EX_template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё исправлено и работает в хроме, в мозиле. изменения можно посмотреть на гитхабе. Позволяет из картинки сделать картинку готовую для размещения на сайте в нормальных размерах, поворачивает исходное изобращение, перемещает, увеличивает/уменьшает и вырезает требуемый фрагмент. делает полный размер и превьюшку. Исключает необходимость использования внешнего редактора для этих целей.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте этот вопрос как принятый.